# AngularJS Material Design code working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I have made a simple program that displays a toolbar using the AngularJS Material Design framework that works on Google Chrome and Opera,however does not work in Firefox, as in, the toolbar is not displayed,only the text inside it is.The code for the html is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="toolbarTest">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SideNav Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\angular\angular-phonecat\app\bower_components\angular-material\angular-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\angular\angular-phonecat\app\bower_components\angular-material\themes\indigo-theme.css">

</head>
<body>
    <script src="C:\angular\angular-phonecat\app\bower_components\angular\angular.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\angular\angular-phonecat\app\bower_components\angular-aria\angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\angular\angular-phonecat\app\bower_components\angular-animate\angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\angular\angular-phonecat\app\bower_components\hammerjs\hammer.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\angular\angular-phonecat\app\bower_components\angular-material\angular-material.js"></script>
    <script >
        angular.module('toolbarTest', ['ngMaterial'])

        .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">

      <md-content flex class="md-padding">

           <md-toolbar md-theme="indigo">
              <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <span>Toolbar: blue-theme</span>
              </h2>
            </md-toolbar>
      </md-content>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to console in Firefox, I get the message "ReferenceError: angular is not defined".
Thank you,any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have a filesystem css and js file references, that could be a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: it wasn't working because Firefox apparently needs the syntax "file:///" before absolute paths.